# gnome-terminal comes up blank

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to get gnome-terminal to run on my system. 
I've tried various installation methods... 
Unfortunately, all of them come up BLANK. 
They also don't accept input.

Wondering if anyone has any knowledge or ideas about this?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of blank gnome-terminal]

Comment: Your screenshot is missing. Have you changed your shell? Does the same problem happen in other terminal emulators?

Comment: my shell is currently set to /bin/bash and my TERM is set to xterm-256color...The problem does not repeat itself in other terminal emulators. Unfortunately, I need to use gnome-terminal for a specific project I'm working on.

Comment: Are you logged in into the GUI as root? Or are you running gnome-terminal as root? What happens if you do everything as your normal user?

Comment: the same issue: http://i.imgur.com/vHsd8aW.png
I should also note that this happens in both debian AND archlinux

Comment: It's not the same, since now you're getting a prompt. What happens when you type at this prompt?

Comment: nothing happens. only the prompt displays when I'm using it as a non-root user, otherwise the behavior is identical. I think the prompt is irrelevant.

Comment: wondering if there are other users who have had better luck with gnome-terminal? or if this could be related to a problem with my xorg.conf?

Comment: It works for me, and for most other people. What distribution are you using? Is this gnome-terminal from the distribution? Does it work if you create a new profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning.  Chances are good that your profile is displaying black text on a black background.

Edit -> Profile Preferences -> (change color scheme.)

Comment: Glad it worked out, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had to uncheck "Use colors from system theme" to get mine to work.